# Call a remote script from another with multiple parameters not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a script that will take input (hardcoded values for now) and call an install PS script and run it on multiple servers. I am using a PSSession and Invoke-Command(see below). The below runs, but does nothing. It doesn't seem to call the other script. Beyond getting it to actually install, I need to know if it was successful or not. I'm pretty novice at Powershell, so any hints/help/suggestions would be great. The below is wrapped in a ForEach to loop the servers with $Computer

```
     Try
     {
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName App02 -Credential $cred

        $sourceInstall = $sourceFolder + 'Install\Install.ps1'
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock{param($serviceName, $installFolder, $sourceFolder, $Action, $username, $password) $sourceInstall} -ArgumentList ($ServiceName, $installFolder, $sourceFolder, $Action, $username, $password)
     }
 Catch
     {
     $Filename = "Error.txt"
         Write-Output "ERROR: Partial Service Deployment. See error log file(s)"
         Add-Content $Filename $_.Exception.Message
     }
     Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: 1) You do not pass `$sourceInstall` variable to remote session. 2) Your remote command just return value of remote `$sourceInstall` variable, but not executing script pointed by it.

Comment: @PetSerAl How do I get the script to run then? Also, if I put a return statement in the install.ps1 script, would that allow error messages to be known to this local script?

Comment: It is depend on PowerShell version. With v3+ you can just `& $using:sourceInstall`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without $Using statement in any version of PowerShell.But pass that too as an argument.

Eg:-

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock
   param($Name)
   & $Command $Name
} -ArgumentList 'Get-Process','Notepad'
```

But you have to pass the arguments positional when using the call operator '&'

```
Get-Help About_Parameters
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters

Regards,

Kvprasoon